# How to create a Quantity selecter with a Item list from a table in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I am creating an application for a self service counter in a restaurant. I have created a table containing menu information such as ITEM_NAME, ITEM_PRICE and a BLOB column with ITEM_IMAGE, what i need to do is create a GUI as the below image,

[Find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qPWf.png)

It should list down the available items with the image and I need a number picker to select the quantity and then pass the value to a collection, also the total also should be updated accordingly.

I tried using cards but I couldn't find a way to add a number picker to the cards. Any help is highly Appreciated
I am using oracle apex 23

Comment: This isn't a pattern I have seen in APEX before, but have a look at the [interactive grid cookbook](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2019/11/04/apex-ig-cookbook-update-for-19-2/) app for samples and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This look isn't readily available OOTB, but! You can certainly recreate it and it isn't anything all too terrible to do. You have some options:

- As Koen mentioned, you can use a report region. Here is a thread of someone else's footprints doing the same thing: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex-tips-include-button-in-each-row-of-interactive-report

  Once you have the buttons, you can set the links to call some logic in your pages, here is some footprints doing that https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/how-to-create-a-link-to-run-pl-sql-process-3412#comment_323462171182340947565285906019349343081

  Then you add the update logic to your collection.

or

- You can create a custom template of the Cards section that works for you, here is a thread of someone else's footprint doing the same thing https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/add-button-to-card-1921#comment_323462171291497277669930003461919386473

  Then you add the update logic to your collection.